# How do i create Symlink to /var/log/myapp to another mount?

Tags: linux, rhel7, symlink, var

I am not very familiar with unix terminologies but I have a requirement where I have installed Gitlab on one of my RHEL server. By default the installation and log goes to `/var/opt/gitlab`and `/var/log/gitlab` respectively.

Gitlab doesn't recommend to change but as my application will grow this mount will become full.
I have got another mound created `/app/gitlab` which has around 200GB of space and I want to move those log files here.

Is there a way to do this without breaking anything? Can we use `symlink` here?
Let me know if anyone can guide me here.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use:

```
mv /var/log/gitlab/* /app/gitlab/
rm -rf /var/log/gitlab
ln -s /app/gitlab /var/log/gitlab
```

or

```
mv /var/log/gitlab/* /app/gitlab/
mount --bind /app/gitlab /var/log/gitlab
```

in mount case you have to add this to fstab too.

Comment: Thank you for the response BUT if i move ```mv /var/log/gitlab/* /app/gitlab/``` then wouldn't my gitlab configuration breaks when i reconfigure or restart it again because in gitlab configuration all the directories are set to ```/var/log/gitlab```. ?

Comment: The symlink points to real Gitlab location, and old paths work transparently.